# Display whole objects in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, json, object, vue.js, vue-component

Problem is that:
I need to display and possible to change JSON. I want to display it as a tree of directory. I don't know how object will be look. It can be like this:

```
"buttons": {
    "login": "LOGIN",
    "register": "REGISTER",
    "next": "Next",
},
"nav": {
    "account": "Acount",
    "login": "Login"
},
```

But sometimes it can be like this:

```
"register": {
    "user": "User",
    "email": "E-mail",
    "language": {
        "en": "English",
        "de": "German",
        "es": "Spanish",
    }
},
"blog": {
    "search": "SEARCH",
    "comments": "COMMENTS"
},
```

The problem is i don't know how nested it will be. I already wrote parser and i parse it into object, but i have no idea how to display it on site.

Comment: try JSON.stringify(yourJSON, null, '\t'); or JSON.stringify(yourJSON, null, ' ');

Comment: its work, but not exactly as I wanted, how i can change now values of that object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use a library?

To display a JSON with a view. I use the very good library
https://leezng.github.io/vue-json-pretty/
.

It takes as a parameter a json of any form.

Good continuation.

Comment: I can, but it allow me to edit values on that json?

Comment: You can do what you want on the object. It's just a data-binding of your Json object to your display. You can always do calculations or change the value of it. If you change it the value will also change in your display.

Comment: Can you acctually help me with that lib? I don't know how to use this higher futures (Get Data) and I can't figured it out from documentation what I do wrong.

Comment: Yes, but I would need more details about your code and the errors received.

Comment: In code I have it like that:         <vue-json-pretty
            :path="'res'"
            :data="uploadedJSON"
            v-model="treeData"
            :highlightMouseoverNode="true"
            @click="handleClick"
        >
        </vue-json-pretty>

Comment: And I dont get that path attribute, how to make it work.

Comment: Here is an example code: [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-53nvd)

Comment: All is happening in 'HelloWorld.vue'.  You must set the variable 'data' and if you do not have a path, you can remove :path="'res'" from the tag.

Comment: I also added '"vue-json-pretty": "^1.6.2"' in the package.json. In the '"dependencies"' section

Comment: Okay, I get that, but how works that pathChecked, I can't get quite how that works

Comment: I do not use. The library must work without. I do not see this property in the doc. Can you tell me where it is?

Comment: It's here on library github https://github.com/leezng/vue-json-pretty

Comment: I look at the documentation on the property 'pathChecked' but it is not clear. I sent an email to the person who developed the library. If I have an answer from that, I'll come back to you.

Comment: Thank you, I will be waiting for answer!

Comment: Yes, I still have not received the answer, but I tell you if he contacts me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `textarea` with a computed property (with getter and setter) as `v-model`.

Something like this:

```html
<textarea v-model="my_JSON_model"></textarea>
```

```js
<script>
    export default {

        data() {
            return {
                my_JSON: {} // import here your json
            }
        },

        computed: {

            my_JSON_model: {

                get() {

                    return JSON.stringify( this.my_JSON , null , '\t' )

                },

                set(val) {

                    this.my_JSON = JSON.parse(val);

                }

            }

        }

    }
</script>
```